# Drush does not get upgraded using composer

Tags: drush, composer

I got the following in *composer.json*:

```
"name": "drupal/drupal",
"description": "Drupal is an open source content management platform powering millions of websites and applications.",
"type": "project",
"license": "GPL-2.0+",
"require": {
    "composer/installers": "^1.0.24",
    "wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin": "^1.4",
    "drush/drush": "^8.1.15",
    "drupal/core": "^8.4.0",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^4.8",
    "drupal/console": "^1.0"
},
"replace": {
    "drupal/core": "^8.4"
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": false,
```

However when I go *composer global update*, drush does not get upgraded as per:

```
vendor/bin/drush --version
Drush Version   :  8.1.9
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Can you paste the relevant lines from the composer output?

Comment: `composer global require drush/drush:^9` will override your current version  constraint

Comment: OK but doing that leaves me this way: `drush up` --> `[Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException] Command "up" is ambiguous (ups, upc and 3 more)`. Then running for instance `drush upc` yields `The pm-updatecode command was deprecated. Please see 'composer outdated' and 'composer update'. For security release notification, see 'drush pm:security'`. What should I do?

Comment: Also `drush pm-update drupal` throws exception `The pm-updatecode command was deprecated. Please see 'composer outdated' and 'composer update'. For security release notification, see 'drush pm:security'`

Comment: @Antonio How you resolved this issue to update D8 core?

Comment: @sarika I had to install Drush globally and use it instead of the Drupal-included one.